# Fill extra column for User

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a `user` table with a `referral` column and this code in `controller/auth`:

```
protected function create(array $data)
    {

        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'referral' => md5($data['email']),
            ]);
    }
```

It adds a `name`, `email` and `password` but not `referral`.

There is no error or notice. What should I do to fill also `referral` column?

Comment: Could you write in English what exactly doesn't work and what do you want to achieve?

Comment: md5 string write to a column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `User` model (probably `app/User.php`, and change:

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];
```

into

```
protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'referral'
    ];
```

You need to add column to fillable to save it.